# Why can't I C-c ' this code block?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I just wanted to start using org-mode to test small ideas, but I've already run into trouble. I have the following problem:

I write:

```
#+begin_src C++

int x = 0;

#+end_src C++
```

Then I hit C-c ', and it tells me: "No special environment to edit here"

Can anyone tell me why this is so? I've had no luck googling it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, it works for me. You do not need the trailing C++ in #+end_src, maybe that is messing up the parser?

Comment: Thank you John, that was it! What a silly mistake. Thank you so much for spotting that!

Comment: Post the answer as an answer. Accept the answer. That removes the question from unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to John Kitchin for the answer!

> You do not need the trailing `C++` in `#+end_src`, maybe that is messing up the parser?

Yes, that was the problem. Without the trailing `C++`, it works.